# Passing Value back to an excel sheet from a dynamically created Form VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a form that will generate dynamically depending on the number of populated rows there are in a give range and that works no problem.

However in this form I want to have several check boxes that will correspond with values in the excel sheet. Think of it being a kind of configuration setting.

The checkboxes are created dynamically because I never know how many settings there will be and are named dynamically but I can't seem to pass the value of the checkbox (T or F) back to the worksheet.

Code for generating the userform

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim edtBox_n As Control
    temp_lastRow = Worksheets("Sources").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    temp_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:A" & temp_lastRow))

    Me.Height = 60 + (temp_count * 24)

    For x = 2 To temp_count

    Set edtBox_n = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.label.1", "ca" & x, True)
    With edtBox_n
        .Caption = Worksheets("Sources").Range("A" & x).Value
        .Top = 12 + (24 * x)
        .Left = 18
        .Height = 18
        .Width = 170
    End With


    Set edtBox_n = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.checkbox.l", "cacb" & x, True)
    With edtBox_n
        .Caption = edtBox_n.Name ' check to find the name of the check box, usually blank
        .Value = Worksheets("Sources").Range("B" & x).Value
        .Top = 12 + (24 * x)
        .Left = 210
        .Height = 18
    End With


    Next x


    End Sub
```

Code for the back/submit button to pass the checkbox values back to the Excel Sheet

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    temp_lastRow = Worksheets("Sources").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    temp_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:A" & temp_lastRow))


    For x = 2 To temp_count

    Worksheets("Sources").Range("B" & x).Value = "cacb" & x.Value

    Next x

    End Sub
```

Comment: What's the exact issue with your current code?

Comment: You actually need to reference the control.  So instead of `"cacb" & x.Value` try `Me.Controls("cacb" & x).Value`

Comment: Thank you so much, the issue I was having was the kept asking for an object, so I tried to create another control and do something similar. I had `Me.("cacb" & x).value` which didn't work.

Thank you again I have spent so long on this.

Answer (score 1):

> You actually need to reference the control. So instead of "cacb" &
>   x.Value try Me.Controls("cacb" & x).Value – Brian M Stafford

Thanks, I added in the suggestion and it works perfectly now.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

temp_lastRow = Worksheets("Sources").UsedRange.Rows.Count
temp_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:A" & temp_lastRow))


For x = 2 To temp_count
Worksheets("Sources").Range("B" & x).Value = Me.Controls("cacb" & x).Value

Next x
End Sub
```